# Like Information

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This query returns the `DBKEY` and `DBPArentProductKEy` results from two tables.

```
select 
    pog.DBKey
    ,pos.DBParentProductKey
    , pro.Name
from ix_spc_planogram as pog with (nolock)
     , ix_spc_position as pos with (nolock)
     , ix_spc_product as pro with (nolock)
where 
     pog.dbkey = pos.dbparentplanogramkey
     and pos.dbparentproductkey=pro.dbkey 
     and pog.Value4= 358
```

**Example:**

```
DBKEY    DBPArentProduct KEy
1        0123
1        0124
1        0125
2        0126
3        0123
3        0124
3        0125
```

I now need a query that will allow me to determine if there are duplicate `DBKEYS` with the exact same products. For Example `DBKEY` 1 has the exact same `DBPArentProductKeys` as DBKEY3. I need to find this out so the duplicates can be identified.Another way to think about this problem is I want to know how many orders have the exact same products with order being `DBKEY` and Products being `DBPAREntPRoductKey`.

If this is possible to do any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We'd like to see some effort that you tried to solve the question on your own - http://whathaveyoutried.com.

Comment: It's also generally considered polite to engage with the community, answering some questions as well as asking them, and accepting answers to your questions when they have been provided.

Answer (score 0):

What flavor of SQL?  Oracle, SQL Server, and MySQL could do it this way...

```
SELECT count(*), DBParentProductKEy
FROM (
    select pog.DBKey
    ,pos.DBParentProductKey
    , pro.Name
    from ix_spc_planogram as pog with (nolock)
    , ix_spc_position as pos with (nolock)
    , ix_spc_product as pro with (nolock)
    where pog.dbkey = pos.dbparentplanogramkey
    and  pos.dbparentproductkey=pro.dbkey 
      and pog.Value4= 358)
GROUP BY DBParentProductKEy
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```